# Nothing is coming up after I run my code？

Tags: c

It is the school exercise, and the original problem is :
Hailstones sequences are ones that seem to always return to 1. The number is halved if
even, and if odd then the next becomes 3*n+1.
The problem is, it compiles well, the complier doesn't yell or anything, but nothing is coming up really.
I wonder why it is? Or are there any errors in my code.
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
int Longest_Hailstone(void);
int Biggest_Hailstone(void);
long Hailstone_generator(long pre_num);
long Comparison(long a,long current_biggest);

//
int main(void){
    int current_longgest=Longest_Hailstone();
    long current_biggest=Biggest_Hailstone();
    printf("The biggest Hailstone Number is:%ld",current_biggest);
    printf("The longgest Hailstone Number is:%d",current_longgest);
}

//Takes in the last number and produce the next hailstone number.
long Hailstone_generator(long pre_num){
    long next_num;
    if(pre_num%2==0){
        next_num=pre_num/2;
    }else{
        next_num=3*pre_num+1;
    }
    return next_num;
}

long Comparison(long a,long current_biggest){
    if(a>current_biggest){
        current_biggest=a;
    }return current_biggest;
}

int Longest_Hailstone(void){
    int intital_num;
    int current_longgest=1;
    int length=0;
    for(intital_num=2;intital_num<=100;intital_num++){//
        while(intital_num>1){
            intital_num=Hailstone_generator(intital_num);
            length++;
        }
        current_longgest=Comparison(length,current_longgest);
    }return current_longgest;
}

int Biggest_Hailstone(void){
    int intital_num;
    int current_biggest=1;
    for(intital_num=2;intital_num<=100;intital_num++){
        while(intital_num>1){
            intital_num=Hailstone_generator(intital_num);
            current_biggest=Comparison(intital_num,current_biggest);
    }
}return current_biggest;
}
```

It compiles right but didn't give me anything either.
I talked to my classmates and they couldn't find anything wrong.
Also, I ran the code on both my laptop and the computer lab PC, it all compiles well but didn't give me anything.
I also set the literation amount to 100(instead of 1000000 in the questions).

Comment: What commands are you using to compile your code? What commands are you using to run your code? What do you mean by "Nothing is coming up," does that mean you are not receiving output at all or the output does not match what you expect?

Comment: The formatting of this code could use some serious work. Whitespace is not evil.

Comment: `intital_num>1` is always true in `while(intital_num>1)` (both places), resulting in an infinite loop. (If your program ends, something must be killing the program for excessive resource use. Its exit code would indicate this.)

Comment: @h0r53 There are no results. Now I know my code is causing an infinite loop so of course there are nothing coming up.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you! I get it right now! I should have use another variables.

Comment: @Chris So I shouldn't place backspace between functions or ...?

Comment: Re "*I should have use another variables.*", Sorry, I didn't realize that you actually did change `intital_num` in the loop. So yeah, you got it exactly right. You clobber `intital_num`, so it never reaches `100`. You should be using a different variable, as you said.

Comment: Re "*So I shouldn't place backspace between functions*", Look at the last three lines. The `}` don't line up, and the `return` should be on its own line.

Comment: Tip: It's spelled "longest"

Comment: Tip: You could calculate the longest and the biggest at the same time. It would be faster.

Comment: @ ikegami Oh! You are right! Thank you! I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `initial_num` is 2 then you pass it to `Hailstone _generator` and get back 1 then the `while (initial_num > 1)` ends and then you increment `initial_num` back to 2 and end up in an infinite cycle so your `Longest_Hailstone()` never returns and your program never gets to the printf's.

A fix could be using different variables for your for cycle and your inner while cycle:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
    intital_num = i;
    while(intital_num > 1){
        intital_num = Hailstone_generator(intital_num);
        length++;
    }
    current_longgest = Comparison(length, current_longgest);
}
```

And same for your other function

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is the loop problem, I am causing a infinite loop so eventually it just keep on running.